# How to use getDeclaredConstructor in AppIntro Library

Tags: android

I'm using AppIntro Library. In Introduction activity, I'm using a slideshow information for my app. Before, For each item I used something like this:

```
addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("Welcome to My HillaVass Test Project","This is The Introduction Activity That Show You Some Information",R.drawable.informetion, Color.DKGRAY));
```

Now I found `newInstance`has been depricated and replaced with `getConstructor().newInstance()`

But I don't know how to set items in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it should be something like this:

```
    SliderPage sliderPage = new SliderPage();
    sliderPage.setTitle(getString(R.string.slider_one_title));
    sliderPage.setTitleColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    sliderPage.setDescription(getString(R.string.slider_one_description));
    sliderPage.setDescColor(Color.GRAY);
    sliderPage.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.informetion);
    sliderPage.setBgColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance(sliderPage));
```